# Troubleshooting Empty API Response and Undefined 'items' Property in React Application

Tags: html, css, reactjs, axios, rapidapi

I'm trying to use the rapid api website to get data for me but all my arrays keep returning empty, I keep getting these errors in my console tab [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoVft.png), and get this in the browser [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh0MF.png), i thought i had all the necessary dependencies so I dont understand why axios is an issue, [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RMpl.png), and none of my arrays return anything [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU3ia.png). The issue only happens when I try to use useEffect to call the fetchFromAPI function.
This is my file structure [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIskt.png). And my components involved:
Feed.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Box, Stack, Typography} from '@mui/material'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Videos  from './Videos';
import { fetchFromAPI } from '../utils/fetchFromAPI';

const Feed = () => {

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('New');
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFromAPI(`search?part=snippet&q=${selectedCategory}`).then((data) => setVideos(data.items))
  }, [selectedCategory]);

  return ( 
    <Stack sx={{flexDirection: {sx: 'column', md: 'row'}}}>
      <Box sx={{height: { sx:'auto', md: '92vh'}, 
      borderRight: '1px solid #3d3d3d', px: {sx:0, md: 2}}}>
        <Sidebar selectedCategory={selectedCategory}
        setSelectedCategory={setSelectedCategory}/>
        <Typography className='copyright' variant='body2' sx={{mt: 1.5, color:'black'}}>
          Copyright 2023 Watcher Media
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box p={2} sx={{overflowY: 'auto', height:'90vh', flex: 2}}>
        <Typography variant='h4'fontWeight='bold' mb={2} sx={{color:'black'}}>
          {selectedCategory} <span style={{color: '#F31503'}} >videos</span>
        </Typography>
        <Videos videos={[]}/> 
      </Box>  
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default Feed
```

fetchFromAPI.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'https://youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com';

const options = {
  params: {
    maxResults: '50'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};
 
export const fetchFromAPI = async (url) => {
  let data;
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${url}`, options); 
    data = response.data;
    console.log(response);
    return data;
}
```

.env:

```
REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY = '-- myRapidAPI-Key--'; // I didn't want to show my actual key on here
```

the code snippet I got from rapidAPI:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com/captions',
  params: {
    part: 'snippet',
    videoId: 'M7FIvfx5J10'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '-- myRapidAPI-Key--',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

try {
    const response = await axios.request(options);
    console.log(response.data);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

videos.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const Videos = ({videos}) => {
  console.log(videos);
  return (
    <div>
    Videos
    </div>
  )
}

export default Videos
```

Comment: 403 would indicate you're attempting to access data you're not allowed to. Can you get the request to work in postman or some other way tot test network calls?

Comment: Hi, I am new with this rapidAPI. can someone please tell me rapidAPI is good to go? actually when I searched through the website to get api translation I got to know some discussions going on like this which is really strange and awful!  this is the [link](https://rapidapi.com/dickyagustin/api/text-translator2/discussions/100877) and this [one](https://rapidapi.com/dickyagustin/api/text-translator2/discussions/108291).   actually I'm in the search of *translate API* so I got to know like. can someone please suggest or give some feedback on this?